# Schmitt Trigger CD40106 has 5V at input with nothing connected

Tags: diodes, pwm, oscillator, potentiometer, schmitt-trigger

I am using Schmitt Trigger CD40106BE to make an PWM oscillator with controllable duty cycles. The schematic is shown below:
[image]
[image]

However, the LED that should be blinking is constantly on. After some trials and errors I found that even when nothing other than Vdd(9V battery) and Vss(ground) are connected to the CD40106, input pins of the chip with nothing connected shows a 5.4V potential difference relative to the ground (battery negative) and the output pins show a 9V (typical behavior).

Why do I have a 5.4V on my input pins with nothing connected?

Comment: Most likely it was oscillating faster than your meter could read with no cap connected , mid scale in the MHz or kHz range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that pin 7 actually measures 0V right at the chip pin - making sure that there is not a loose connection on the ground due to the sometimes unreliable solderless breadboard.

It's also possible the chip is damaged or it is not a CD40106, but it's unlikely that damage would affect all the inputs at once.

Comment: The chip is damaged and the measurement of all pins are ~4.5V. Thanks!